# GitLab CI: MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT not triggered by update?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm testing GitLab CI pipelines.

I have created a merge request named "TEST" that have its `gitlab-ci.yml` with a rule like below:

```yaml
if '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE == "TEST"'
```

It worked fine as I expected. Create event triggered the `merge_request_event`.
However, if I create a merge request have another title and then I update it to "TEST", It doesn't seems to trigger the `merge_request_event`.

According to [this document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html), `merge_request_event` is supposed to be triggered by updated too.

> For pipelines created when a merge request is created or updated. Required to enable merge request pipelines, merged results pipelines, and merge trains.

Do I take it wrong or missed important information or documents?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is correct, but perhaps the meaning is not 100% clear.

> For pipelines created when a merge request is created or updated.

Stated more precisely:

*When an MR action **creates a pipeline***, `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` will be equal to `merge_request_event`

However, it does not mean to imply that any update will create a pipeline. Updating the MR title does not create a pipeline, so this is not applicable to that scenario.

However, after you have changed the title, if some other event creates a new pipeline (specifically: push events to the MR source branch or manually running a new pipeline on the MR), the rule will evaluate to true and the job will be included in the created pipeline.

[Per the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html):

> Merge request pipelines:
>
> - Run when you:
>
>   - Create a new merge request.
>   - Push a new commit to the source branch for a merge request.
>   - Select Run pipeline from the Pipelines tab in a merge request.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing to a branch will trigger a pipeline, and if that branch has an associated Merge Request, then the variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` will be equal to `merge_request_event`.

On the other hand, afaik just editing the title of a Merge Request on the GitLab UI will *not* trigger a pipeline, so your logic will never be evaluated unless you also push to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an existing bug with the CI/CD env vars for Merge Requests, where the subsequent pipelines after the initial MR is opened are relegated to `push` rather than `merge_request_event` for the `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369383#note_1239166213